# How can I config log4j for send wowza logs?

Tags: log4j, wowza

I want to send the wowza logs to a remote server that has a logstash installed. For that, I want to use log4j but doesn´t work, this is my config:

Access appender (UDP) - uncomment and add to rootCategory list on first line log4j.appender.serverAccessUDP=com.wowza.wms.logging.UDPAppender log4j.appender.serverAccessUDP.remoteHost=x.x.x.x

log4j.appender.serverAccessUDP.port=5678 log4j.appender.serverAccessUDP.layout=com.wowza.wms.logging.ECLFPatternLayout log4j.appender.serverAccessUDP.layout.Fields=x-severity,x-category,x-event;date,time,c-client-$ log4j.appender.serverAccessUDP.layout.OutputHeader=true log4j.appender.serverAccessUDP.layout.QuoteFields=false log4j.appender.serverAccessUDP.layout.Delimeter=tab

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know and Wowza said, no direct support of logstash yet (See answers for your question on wowza forums https://www.wowza.com/community/questions/46469/how-can-i-config-log4j-for-send-wowza-logs.html )

Our solution was to send logs with syslog to logstash server. Logstash has syslog input plugin.

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, serverAccess

# Console appender
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=com.wowza.wms.logging.ECLFPatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.Fields=x-severity,x-category,x-event,x-ctx,x-comment
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.OutputHeader=false
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.QuoteFields=false
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.Delimiter=space

#SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.serverAccess=org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.serverAccess.Facility=LOCAL1
log4j.appender.serverAccess.FacilityPrinting=false
log4j.appender.serverAccess.Header=true
log4j.appender.serverAccess.syslogHost={SYSLOG_IP_PORT}
log4j.appender.serverAccess.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.serverAccess.layout.ConversionPattern={HOSTNAME}: [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] %5p [%t] --- %c : %m%n
```

The {SYSLOG_IP_PORT} is the target logstash server ip:port.

{HOSTNAME} should be replaced. If you would like to know from the message which "instance", server was sending the given message, fill it with the server's hostname for example.

The "Console appender" is optional, sometimes is good for debug, can comment out in production.